# Let's + verb / let's do some + ing (7.8 added later)

Tags: grammar

1. Let's wash the dishes.
2. Let's do some washing up.
3. Let's wash the lundury.
4. Let's do some wahing.
5. Let's garden.
6. Let's do some gardening.
7. Let's wheel.
8. Let's do some wheeling.

Which versions are natural?

Comment: In the general sense, it's contextual. Different verbs are used in different ways. And sometimes other words are used instead of _do_ – such as _go_ or _take_. For example, "Let's ***go*** for a walk" seems rather common, as does "Let's ***take*** a nap." I don't think I'd say, "Let's walk" instead of, "Let's take a walk," except as part of a longer sentence (e.g., "Let's walk to the beach"). I don't know why you're asking about _washing_ and _gardening_, and not, say, _eating_ and _talking_, or maybe _driving_ and _arguing_. This might be too vague or too broad.

Answer (score 1):

I would reword #2 and #4 as follows, but this may be dialect-specific (British English may differ from American English):

> Let's do **the** washing up.
>   Let's do **the** washing.

If you used *some*, it would sound to me like you didn't intend to do the entirety of the washing/washing up. Maybe there are three plates (or t-shirts) to be cleaned, and you only intend to do two.

As a further note, just in case you don't know, *washing up* refers to dish-washing and washing cutlery and kitchen utensils, while *the washing* will generally refer to laundry.

---

Taking into account the suggestions of the first part of my answer, I'd say the only one there that doesn't sound completely natural is #3. It would be much more common to hear:

> Let's **do** the laundry.

The washing is implied, since you're unlikely to do much else to laundry. Although, you could say *hang (out) the laundry* if you wanted to speak about putting the washed laundry on a washing line to dry.

Further, while "*let's garden*" is definitely used, "*let's do some gardening*" will be the more common phrase for inviting someone to do work in the garden. Compare with "*let's run*" and "*let's go running.*"

Comment: Thank you. It's helpful, especially the difference between the and some. So you think there aren't much mistakes except #3. Then In this regard, can  you explan why "let's wheel (playing with a bike trailer) or let's do some wheeling" can't match the usage? You might not use "wheel" in the form of verb, but what if we assume that there is the verb "wheel", can these two sentences also follow the forms above suggested? If not, what make them to be impossible?

Comment: There is a verb [*to wheel*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/wheel) (Oxford Dictionaries), but it requires an object to be used in the sense you want to use it in. I'd say that the only reason you can't use *to wheel* in that way is because *to wheel* isn't used in that way. There are similar phrases (like *let's ride* for bikes), but *let's wheel* just isn't a phrase.

Comment: Thank you. 1. Isn't a phrase means is not a common use? But then if I say it, you would understand, and consider it correctly spoken,  is that it? 2. How about this sentence "let's do some wheeling"? 3. If both are all incorrect, what would you say someone to play with a bike trailer, when the someone already know what the verb "wheel" means?

Comment: With all respect, I would recommend keeping discussion on [one of your other questions](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/98263/lets-wheelpush-a-stroller) constrained to that ELL post.